# Print an integer NASM

Tags: arrays, assembly, nasm

I'm trying to read 3 numbers from the user and I store them in an array then I show them using paul carter functions in NASM here is my code :

```
%include "asm_io.inc"

SECTION .bss 

tab resb 3

SECTION .data 
msg db "Un nombre :",10 

SECTION .text 
 global main 
      main:
    mov esi,tab 
    xor ecx,ecx 
get_data:   
    mov eax,msg 
    call print_string 
    call read_int 
    mov [esi+ecx],eax   
    inc ecx 
    cmp ecx,3 
    jne get_data
    call print_nl
    xor ecx,ecx 
    mov edi,tab 
print_data: 
    mov eax,[edi+ecx]
    call print_int 
    inc ecx 
    cmp ecx,3 
    jne print_data 






    mov eax,1 ; exit code 
    int 0x80 ; call exit
```

The problem is that is doesn't execute print_data loop and it exit .

Comment: You've only reserved 3 bytes for `tab`. If you wanted 3 dwords you should use `resd 3` instead of `resb 3`, and you should be incrementing `ecx` by 4 instead of 1 at the end of each iteration. Also, I don't how the functions in `asm_io.inc` are implemented, but `ecx` is typically a _caller-saved_ register, which means that you shouldn't rely on it keeping its value across a function call. Your `msg` string also appear to lack a NUL terminator byte.

Comment: I have modified the program as you said expect that `ecx` register is not used by these function but it still skipping that loop

Comment: It cannot skip the loop. But maybe it is not printing the result you want to see. By the way, it is very hard to read asm-code without comments from the person who wrote it. And when you added changes to the code, update the code in your question. In addition to that you need to describe what the functions, you are calling, actually do.

Answer (score 0):

Just to be clear. Are these the changes you did? Even if the ECX register is not used as an input or output for a particular function it might still be used internally. That's what Michael meant with *'ecx is typically caller-saved'*

```
%include "asm_io.inc"

SECTION .bss 

tab resd 3

SECTION .data 
msg db "Un nombre :",10,0

SECTION .text 
global main 
main:
mov edi,tab 
xor ecx,ecx 
get_data:
push ecx   
mov eax,msg 
call print_string 
call read_int 
mov [edi+ecx*4],eax   
pop ecx
inc ecx 
cmp ecx,3 
jne get_data
call print_nl
mov esi,tab
xor ecx,ecx  
print_data: 
push ecx
mov eax,[esi+ecx*4]
call print_int 
pop ecx
inc ecx 
cmp ecx,3 
jne print_data 

mov eax,1 ; exit code 
int 0x80 ; call exit
```

Comment: I have done all this modification and tried to push all registers even those witch are not used in the loop but i still have the same problem n and by the way if you get a look at Paul carter documentation ( his book ) you will find that he doesn't push any register before calling a function .

Comment: Are the segment registers setup correctly? The **book** says "The early programs in this text will all start from the simple C driver program in Figure 1.6. It simply calls another function named asm main. This is really a routine that will be written in assembly.  First, this lets the C system set up the program to run correctly in protected mode. All the segments and their corresponding segment registers will be initialized by C."